# Customizing external embed widget

Tags: javascript, css, styles, zendesk

I've been trying to customize an embedded widget from Zendesk on my website. Since they don't give any option to customize the look of its form, I would like to enforce my css rules.

I added this piece of code from Zendesk to have their form on my page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://leads-capturer.futuresimple.com/embed.js?token=ca98908sdgfgds9834234jlkjsdb">
```

This script places a form within an `<iframe>` and all nodes inside this `<iframe>` cannot be customized/changed.

I tried JS to set an inline style to form elements inside the `<iframe>`. Tried create a new stylesheet to override their original stylesheet but nothing seems to work.

Even something as simple as this code below, fails (`#iframe-main-container` is a child from `<iframe>`):

```
<script>
    let p = document.querySelector('#iframe-main-container');
    p.style.background = 'red';
</script>
```

If I change the code above and target `<iframe>`, it works.

My first question would be, is it possible to override an existing CSS rule from an embedded widget?

If this is possible, am I doing something wrong to change its looks?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
  <script>
    let iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
    let p = iframe[0].contentWindow.document.getElementById('#iframe-main-container');
    p.style.background = 'red';
  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Rob Moll Your suggested code is returning 'undefined' for that selector. I believe this script is being executed before DOM is ready. I tried a couple of tricks here such as: '  $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log($('#iframe-main-container').css('padding-bottom'));
});' another try was executing a setTimeout function after 5 seconds to read a css value from #iframe-main-container but I'm always getting 'undefined' as its value. Any thoughts?